# A mac app that allows diagramming and handwritten notes, almost like a whiteboard app, that works w/ drawing tablets?

Tags: osx, note-taking, drawing

Basically something to do software architecture diagrams on and to write handwritten notes.

I guess something like a white board application for the mac.  Needs to work with a drawing tablet.   I find a lot of apps for ipads, but nothing much for macs that isn't ancient.